# Chromium launcher is no longer in usr/share/applications

Tags: lubuntu, launcher, chromium

so I recently got myself Lubuntu 20.04, i'm a new user of Linux so I'm still kinda lost.
So I just downloaded Chromium by using "Discover". But when I tried to put in my desktop, I did a mistake and removed the app from the /usr/share/applications so now Chromium is no longer in my app list and i have to use "Discover" to launch it. I don't know how to get it back. I'm sorry if this is not clear i'm not a very good english speaker and i'm also a new user on Lubuntu so very sorry. Thanks you for your help !

Rémi.

Comment: A `dpkg -S /usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` on my system reports the file is found in the `chromium-browser` package (https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/chromium-browser), as can be seen with https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/amd64/chromium-browser/filelist . You could extract it from that deb (a compressed file like a zip), or `sudo apt install --reinstall chromium-browser`

Comment: If it was a snap install you'll probably have a copy of that file in `/var/lib/snapd/desktop/applications/`